# PHP MySQL query displaying results in weird order

Tags: php, mysql

I have two sets of 4 rating inputs in a database table, one with a `priority_id` of 19 and the other with the `priority_id` of 20.  If I run the sql query below in phpMyAdmin it will return the values for the `id` primary key field and list them in the right order.  If I run my php file and select the values for `priority_id` 19 they display to the screen in the right order. However, if I select the values for `priority_id` 20 the id values display to screen in a weird, irrational order.  Anyone have ideas what might be causing this?  I've tried adding the `order by` to the sql query but that doesn't seem to help.

```
$input_ids = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM rating_inputs WHERE priority_id = '20'";
echo $query . "<br/>";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$z=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $input_ids[$z] = $row['id'];
    echo "input id: " . $input_ids[$z] . "<br/>";
    $z=$z+1;
}
```

These are my database fields and their data.  The value field is empty at the moment.

id | priority_id | category_id | value

```
53 | 19 | 1  |
54 | 19 | 4  |
55 | 19 | 10 | 
56 | 19 | 11 | 
57 | 20 | 1  | 
58 | 20 | 4  | 
59 | 20 | 10 | 
60 | 20 | 11 |
```

Comment: can you show the records?

Comment: are you sure that ORDER BY won't work?

Comment: phpmyadmin usually adds an order by, try to use "OPTIMIZE TABLE", sometimes it acts strange after many insert/delete operations (also w/o ORDER BY the results are in table order not ID). Also state if you have a primary key. Run an "EXPLAIN SELECT" to see if the query uses the proper index. Use PDO , mysql_ are deprecated for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Records have no intrinsic order in the database. The order in which they're retrieved is random for all intents and purposes. If they are in any particular order, it's because they happened to be stored in that order or were encountered in the index in that order.

If you expect a particular order, use an `ORDER BY` clause in the query.

Comment: I'm trying to post my records, though I'm not very familiar with this site yet.  I guess I have to edit my original post?

Comment: Yeah, comments aren't the place to post a lot of data.

Comment: I was mistaken, the issue is even occurring inside phpMyAdmin.  I've done a OPTIMIZE TABLE and a REPAIR TABLE, both didn't solve the problem.  id is the primary key, set to auto_increment.

Comment: Here's the query that seems to work.
SELECT * FROM `rating_inputs` WHERE priority_id = 20 order by category_id desc

Comment: Also "order by id asc" is working now. Strange it doesn't work when I use single quotes around the field (order by 'id' asc). Hopefully this helps someone else. Thanks for all your help guys!